# Russian equivalent of "carve out (time)"

Tags: выражения

> Mornings may never be stress-free times of zen-like bliss, but at least you can **carve out a minute or two** to enjoy your coffee before the day really gets going.

What are some commonly used Russian expressions for "carve out (time)"? I might say the following in conversation:

> выкроить минутку-другую на чашечку кофе

Comment: another one is **выделить**, however it's more formal or may connote lack of desire to spend time at someone else's request and doing it by way of favor

Answer (score 8):

Right. You can definitely use the phrase "**выкроить время/минутку-другую/часок-другой для чего-то/на что-то**".

Alternatively, you may use "**найти время**", "**урвать минутку/часок**":

> Мне нужно научиться **находить время** для себя.
>
> Я **урвала** часок для чтения, и это помогло мне отвлечься.
>
> Я даже не могу **выкроить время** для звонка подруге!

Note that "урвать" and "выкроить" make the whole sentence more emotional. They emphasize how time-poor the speaker/writer is. While "находить время" is not that emotional and emphatic. It's just for stating the fact.